# Is *Conservation of Distinction* a true conservation law in mainstream physics?

Tags: symmetry, causality, unitarity, quantum-states

Both Leonard Susskind and Francis Heylighen have written about the *Conservation of Distinction* but it seems Susskind more closely connects this (law?) with unitarity in quantum mechanics. Heylighen doesn't mention unitarity from what I've read and uses the term more to argue the foundations and meaning of causality.

So is the *Conservation of Distinction* a true law of conservation in mainstream physics?

And if it is a law of conservation, what rule of symmetry does it correspond to (assuming Noether's theorem applies)?

Comment: Where did Susskind write about this?

Comment: Could you summarize in your question what the "conservation of distinction" is? I'd imagine many other people like me are familiar with unitarity but not this phrase.

Comment: From what you say, it appears to be an alternate name for unitarity which is easier for the layperson to understand. Nothing much more.

Comment: @probably_someone  Susskind mentions it it in his book "Quantum Mechanics, The Theoretical Minimum"

Comment: Do you have a link to this, as I've never heard of it? If it's in Susskinds book, it might be worthwhile to quote the relevant paragraph to give some context.

Comment: Does Susskind reference Heylighen's work specifically when he mentions conservation of distinction? It's possible that the two uses of the term are actually referring to two unrelated concepts.

Comment: @octonion I'm still trying to understand myself. I believe it's the linear independence of quantum states - that this is conserved?

Comment: @probably_someone - re Heylighen, no. I came across some of his work through Google search to research the topic.

Comment: @MoziburUllah sorry dont have the book with me now, but can follow up with that in about 3 - 4 hours. Susskind mentions a 'minus 1' law in classical mechanics - the conservation of information. And if I recall relates that to unitarity in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @docscience Conservation of the inner product of quantum states (which determines whether they are orthogonal) is a direct consequence of the unitarity of the time evolution operator. I think knzhou is right that this "conservation of distinction" is just a way to point out a feature of unitarity that doesn't sound so mathematical.

Comment: Please do. Given the relevance of information to probability and probability with unitarity; the conservation of information seems a lot more plausible.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone gave a precise reference for this. One place where he discusses it is in his [theoretical minimum lecture series on quantum mechanics](https://youtu.be/x0m2sQuAr34?t=987). When he refers to "conversation of distinctions", he is indeed referring to the notion that time evolution operators (which are unitary), preserve orthogonality of quantum states.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an [article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01969728908902213?journalCode=ucbs20) by Heylighen on this; it appears he's interested in theorising causality judging from the abstract:

> Equal causes have equal effects is reformulated as a distinction conserving relation. Unpredictable, respectively irreversible processes are analysed as processes in which distinctions are created, respectively destroyed. Different types of partially and pseudo causal relations are examined. Time order is derived from distinction conservation.

So in brief, from Heylighers perspective this is an underlying conservation law that gives time order. It's not a main-stream conservation law of physics which is no comment upon its validity or truth.