# Conservation of Distinctions in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, unitarity, quantum-states

Recently I have been reading Quantum Mechanics The Theoretical Minimum by Leonard Susskind. In the book he mentions the law of conservation of distinctions, i.e. the conservation of information.

He mentions that if two isolated systems start at  different states, they will continue to stay in different states. So say I have two different systems in states $|A⟩$ and $|B⟩$, and after some time they reach states $|A'⟩$ and $|B'⟩$. Since the states were distinct $⟨B|A⟩=0$, and since distinctions are conserved $⟨B'|A'⟩=0$

Does it mean that the measurement we make are also distinct? (for instance let's say that the state A is spin up and state B is spin down initially, so does it mean that the spins of both the systems will be different when we measure them again?)

Comment: Is the system isolated?

Comment: @kevin012 yes the systems are isolated.

Comment: Reading the discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/403591/is-conservation-of-distinction-a-true-conservation-law-in-mainstream-physics), it seems Susskind is using an unnecessarily confusing phrasing for the preservation of the inner product in unitary transformations, as in [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_transformation).

Comment: @secavara I have understood what he meant to say, " if the state vectors are orthogonal in the beginning, they are orthogonal at all points of time", my question is if the state vectors being orthogonal means that the observations are also distinct?

Comment: I'd assume it depends on your observables. The fact that your states are orthogonal does not mean their projections in all the shared eigenspaces are orthogonal, or, in other words, it does not mean that all their quantum numbers have to be different. They could share the same quantum number in one observable and still be orthogonal, meaning that measuring that quantity will give the same result for both.

Comment: @secavara I got your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Quantum Mechanics, two systems being in distinct states doesn't necessarily mean that they show distinct observations upon being acted by various operators. Consider the following scenario where the observable $L$ acts on the states $|A'⟩$ and $|B'⟩$. This may be written as follows.

$$L|A'⟩=\alpha_i|\lambda_i⟩$$
$$L|B'⟩=\beta_j|\lambda_j⟩$$

Where $|\lambda_i⟩$ are the Eigen vectors of the observable $L$. Now on measurement, this would lead to the state to collapse into one of the Eigen vectors, and as there is no condition that none of the Eigen vectors that represents state $|A'⟩$ also represent $|B'⟩$ (this is the important part, make sure you understand this) it means that there is a possibility that the observation of both states might lead to the same state.